# I need help converting this array of objects into an array of arrays

Tags: javascript

I have the following array of objects:

```
    [
{
    "messages": {
        "m1": {
            "message": "Relay malfunction found. Cause: moth.",
            "sender": "ghopper"
        }
    },
    "title": "Historical Tech Pioneers",
    "key": "one"
} ]
```

But I wish to convert it to an array of arrays. For example: I want to turn the title field below:

```
    "title": "Historical Tech Pioneers"
```

Into:

```
    "title": [ "Historical Tech Pioneers" ]
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: For what? Why would one need that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: Maybe `const arrayify = obj => Object.values(obj).map(o => typeof o === "object" ? arrayify(o) : o);` ?

Comment: I have tried using the Array.from() method ib the array but that did not work.

Comment: I need it for a Dialog flow and Google assistant request, response process

Comment: This could be solved using native/vanilla javascript with an array iteration method like `map` (check out this for details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Alternatively if you can use external libraries, consider checking out LoDash (https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4).

Comment: Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the declaration:

```
var myArr = [
  {
    "messages": {
      "m1": {
        "message": "Relay malfunction found. Cause: moth.",
        "sender": "ghopper"
      }
    },
    "title": "Historical Tech Pioneers",
    "key": "one"
  }
];
```

You can iterate over each element and reassign the property using:

```
myArr.forEach(o => o.title = [o.title]);
```

Or without ES6:

```
myArr.forEach(function (o) {
  o.title = [o.title]);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked.

Comment: @Obi, great, you can accept the answer if you think that was the most relevant for your initial question. Both of us will get rep.